# Entity Framework Core group by date range

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I try to bring totals according to the days, but sometimes the days can be elongated. For example, a time period of one day is between 00:00 and 23:59. When you make the following code according to this timeframe, it doesn't matter, it gives the correct totals.

```
                opening = opening.AddDays(-6);

                var totals = await _unitOfWork.Additions.GetAll().Where(x => x.FirmId == firm.FirmId && x.State == false && x.Closing >= opening && x.Closing <= closing)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Closing.Value.Year, x.Closing.Value.Month, x.Closing.Value.Day })
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    onKey = Convert.ToDateTime(new DateTime(s.Key.Year, s.Key.Month, s.Key.Day)).ToShortDateString(),
                    total = s.Sum(c => c.Price)

                }).ToListAsync();
```

However, opening and closing hours may vary according to the enterprises, so the day totals do not give the correct results for each enterprise.

For example, if a business's opening time is between 07:00 in the morning and 02:00 in the night, the above block of code will not work correctly. Because, assuming the last closed account is 01:00 at night, the code block above assigns this closed account to another day because the closed account is closed on the new day.

But what I want is that I need the sum of a business between morning opening and night closing time.

For example, --->

Company 1 **opening** : 07:00 A.M **closing** : 23:59 PM **time range** [07:00-23:59] output --> *18.11.2019 **total**: 1000$

Company 2 **opening** : 07:00 A.M **closing** : 02:00 AM (next day 19.11.2019 ) **time range** [07:00-02:00] output --> 18.11.2019 **total**: 1200$

I tried this solution but I got the 'must be reducible node' error.

```
                try
                {

                    TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(firm.OpeningHours.Split('-')[0].Split(':')[0]), Convert.ToInt32(firm.OpeningHours.Split('-')[0].Split(':')[1]), 0);

                    var totals = await _unitOfWork.Additions.GetAll().Where(x => x.FirmId == firm.FirmId && x.State == false && x.Closing >= opening && x.Closing <= closing)
                    .GroupBy(x =>
                            new {
                                Y = x.Closing.Value.Year,
                                M = x.Closing.Value.Month,
                                D = x.Closing.Value.TimeOfDay >= start ? x.Closing.Value.Day : x.Closing.Value.Day - 1
                            })
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        onKey = Convert.ToDateTime(new DateTime(s.Key.Y, s.Key.M, s.Key.D)).ToShortDateString(),
                        total = s.Sum(c => c.Price)

                    }).ToListAsync();


                    return new BaseResponse<object>(totals);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return new BaseResponse<object>("null");
                }
```

DB provider which I am using is Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Comment: So, you won't be able to group by Year, Month and Day because those don't apply to a "business day".  Those are calendar days.  You need to define your business day and then group by it.

Comment: @devlincarnate So, how can I do this logically ?

Comment: Are these opening hours stored in `Firm`?

Comment: @GertArnold yes I stored in firm entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get accurate results if you adjust your group by expression. The effective closing date for each addition depends on the firm opening hours. Something like this should work:

```
var totals = await _unitOfWork
    .Additions
    .GetAll()
    .Where(x => 
        x.FirmId == firm.FirmId && 
        x.State == false && 
        x.Closing >= opening && 
        x.Closing <= closing)
    .GroupBy(x => 
        new { 
            x.Closing.Value.Year, 
            x.Closing.Value.Month, 
            (x.Closing.Value.TimeOfDay >= firm.OpeningHours)? x.Closing.Value.Day : x.Closing.Value.Day - 1         
            })          
    .Select(s => new
    {
        onKey = Convert.ToDateTime(new DateTime(s.Key.Year, s.Key.Month, s.Key.Day)).ToShortDateString(),
        total = s.Sum(c => c.Price)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: what should be stored in firm.Openinghours ?, my firm.openinghours entity stored string value -->> ex. "07:00-02:00"

Comment: first time is A.M second time stored in P.M Value

Comment: Day = (x.Closing.Value.TimeOfDay >= TimeSpan.Parse(firm.OpeningHours.ToString())) ?  x.Closing.Value.Day : x.Closing.Value.Day - 1 ------ not working

Comment: I forgot to say, I use the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Comment: I assumed firm.OpeningHours would have a timespan value, not a string.

Comment: Your solution good to work but I got the "must be reducible node" error.